# Teleric table filtering problem in Asp.Net Web Form

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik

I want to filter on a column in a telerik table. Here I am entering a value into the filterbox. Then I want it to list the data with the entered value. For this, I press the "enter" key. Then the same list is listed again without filtering in the way I want and the value in the filterbox is deleted.

`<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="User Phone" HeaderStyle-CssClass="bannerName" AllowFiltering="true" ShowFilterIcon="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" SortExpression="UserPhone" DataField="UserPhone" Resizable="False"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Literal ID="EducationCodeLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserPhone") %>'></asp:Literal> </ItemTemplate> </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>`

When I do this again, the filtering occurs as I want and the data is listed. I can do this properly when I use filters on other columns, but it doesn't happen the first time on my 1 column. What I want is for this to list the data when I press the "enter" key first. How can I solve this.